# Load a solution on launching Visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have added Visual studio to my startup folder in windows, now I want that when it launches it should load a particular solution by default. So that I don't have to check from the recent projects and select them.

So when my windows starts it launches visual studio and loads this solution and I am ready to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have devenv.exe added in startup, the next step is to add the argument with the path to the solution.

1. Right click the shortcut to devenv.exe under your startup folder.
2. Click properties.
3. Update the target field from

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

to something like this

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" "C:\Your path\HelloWorld.sln"

You can see additional information about Devenv Command Line Switches [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a shortcut to your .sln solution file to the startup folder instead of a shortcut to VS. It will load VS with this solution.